# LINQ XML Read different hierarchies into 1 object

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file

```
<searchResponse requestID=“500” status=“success”>
    <pso>
        <psoID ID=“770e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655448549”
        targetID=“mezeoAccount”/>
        <data>
            <email>user2@example.net</email>
            <quotaMeg>100</quotaMeg>
            <quotaUsed>23</quotaUsed>
            <realm>Mezeo</realm>
            <path>/san1/</path>
            <billing>user2</billing>
            <active>true</active>
            <unlocked>true</unlocked>
            <allowPublic>true</allowPublic>
            <bandwidthQuota>1000000000</bandwidthQuota>
            <billingDay>1</billingDay>
        </data>
    </pso>
</searchRequest>
```

and I want to extract the data into a single business object.  Am I better to go

```
MezeoAccount mcspAccount = new MezeoAccount();
mcspAccount.PsoID = doc.Element("psoID").Attribute("ID").Value;
mcspAccount.Email = doc.Element("email").Value;
...
```

or build a list even though I know there is only 1 record in the file?

```
var psoQuery = from pso in doc.Descendants("data")
    select new MezeoAccount {
        PsoID = pso.Parent.Element("psoID").Attribute("ID").Value,
        Email = pso.Element("email").Value,
        ... };
```

What would people suggest would be the more correct way, or a better way even, if I missed something.

Comment: What is the schema on your XML input?  Specifically, are the elements of `searchResponse/pso/data` required or can they be left out?  If they can be left out, do they have default values?  But the second option you put is really just syntactic sugar so you don't have to repeatedly re-write the variable name.

Comment: ...and you can use that syntactic sugar anywhere - not just in a LINQ query. Jesper's answer does so.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this question? Perhaps if you solved this question first, your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195671/xdocument-parses-but-isnt-searchable-from-string would be easier to solve. I have posted an answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: Notice also that there are a couple of errors in your XML file:the start tag has no matching end tag, and some invalid characters: “ and ”.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your xml only will contain one record of the data in mind you shouldn't create a list for it. So your first example looks fine.

A pattern I personally use is something like this:

```
public class MezeoAccount 
{
    public string PsoID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public static MezeoAccount CreateFromXml(XmlDocument xml)
    {
        return new MezeoAccount() 
        {
            PsoID = xml.Element("psoID").Attribute("ID").Value,
            Email = doc.Element("email").Value;
        };
    }
}

//Usage
var mezeoAccount = MezeoAccount.CreateFromXml(xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't get a working answer to this question. Assuming that there can only be one account in the XML file, I would do it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class MezeoAccount
{
    public string PsoId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int QuotaMeg { get; set; }
    // Other properties...
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
        XElement pso = doc.Element("searchResponse").Element("pso");
        XElement data = pso.Element("data");
        MezeoAccount x = new MezeoAccount
        {
            PsoId = pso.Element("psoID").Attribute("ID").Value,
            Email = data.Element("email").Value,
            QuotaMeg = int.Parse(data.Element("quotaMeg").Value),
            // Other properties...
        };
    }
}
```